# Match path with wildcard in Express

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I would like Express to route `/m/objectID` and `/m/someslug/ObjectID` to the same function. I have the following:

```
app.get("/m/:id",...);
app.get("/m/(.*)/:id", ...);
```

and the top route works fine, but the bottom one doesn't. I think that my regex isn't correct - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/m/(.*?)/:id
```

Try this.Make `*` non greedy.

or

```
/m/([^/]+)/:id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second one worked. I suppose the [] are required to limit the scope of the regex?

Comment: @Alexander yes that is the best way to structure a regex when to stop.